# Is it possible to check how an item will display on the website before saving it to be uploaded?

Tags: magento2, product, view

I Want to make sure my item will be uploaded, viewed and interacted with correctly, can I check what it would look like prior to putting it live on the site available to customers?

Comment: What about setting up a dev/testing area where you can try out stuff?

Comment: Hi Ryan, is this something like a product page preview option?

Answer (score 0):

For this, you can just make a staging of the site. In which you can create your product and check it on frontend. When you like the frontend (how product is showing), you can just simply do the same in your live site.

For creating staging site you can ask your server support or developer to do this.